# Incorrect calculation result (possible overflow)

Tags: r

Performing `(-954437177*4294895519) %% 4294967296` in R gives `1908882432` instead of `1908882329`. Is there a way in R to compute the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

Use a package that supports larger integers (e.g. gmp):

```
library(gmp)
> mod.bigz(-as.bigz(954437177)*as.bigz(4294895519), as.bigz(4294967296))
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1908882329
```